# ios InApp purchases: When and why does SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored get sent back as status of a transaction?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, in-app-billing

iOS In-App purchases: When and why does `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` get sent back as status of a transaction?

Does it related to having a recurring subscription plan?

Answer (score 2):

You get `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` transactions instead of `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` transactions when you are restoring the user's purchases by sending a `restoreCompletedTransactions` message to the `SKPaymentQueue`.

Comment: So...  `Restored` transactions were previously `Purchased` and then `Finished`?  I assume they should not be `Finished` again?

Answer (score 1):

General rule is to process both callbacks: for purchase and restore purchase.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
[self recordTransaction: transaction content:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
[self recordTransaction: transaction content:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```